# where varcharcol = 0 returns all rows

Tags: mysql-5.5

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
create table mytable(cola int primary key, colb varchar(10));
```

Let's put some data in it:

```
insert into mytable values(1, 'abc');
insert into mytable values(2, 'def');
```

When I select using this query:

```
select * from mytable where colb = 0;
```

I get **ALL** rows.

Please note colb data type is varchar, but I use 0 as value. If I use 1 or other integers, I get no rows.

Why is that? Is there a setting to prevent this behavior?

BTW mysql 5.5.9 for windows.

Comment: I bet your varchar is silently casted as some numeric type and that gives a value of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused MySQL's sloppy data type checking. As far as I know there is no workaround, except to write correct SQL.

In general it is highly recommended to **never** rely on implicit data type conversion. Make sure your literals match the datatype of the column.

So you should write:

```
select * from mytable where colb = '0';
```